# Paginate across two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I got two tables and wondering if it's possible to join them into one query.

the script gets a `catID` as GET, it should then list all the subCats(if any) and then list the photos that are in the mainCat `cat = catID and subcat = 0`

`subCats` table is:

`id | parentCat | title | addedBy | date | active | defaultPhoto`

`photos` table is: `id | title | description | fileName | fileType | uploadedBy | time | cat | subCat`

I got a pagination script that takes a count and generates a LIMIT to use. Wondering if I can combine this into one query for both tables some how to make pagination easier with what I got already. So one selects the count for both with the join, then another selects the results.

Any ideas? Really stuck on this.

This is my messy start but it seems like a bad design so far:

```
<?php
    if ($catInfoResult = $db->select("SELECT * FROM cats WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1", $catID))
    {
        if ($db->numRows > 0)
        {
            $pageTitle = h($catInfoResult[0]['title']) . ' - Photo Gallery';
            ?>
                <div class="headingTitle"><?=h($catInfoResult[0]['title'])?> Photos</div>
            <?php

            //get subCats
            $subCatCountResult = $db->count('subCats', '*', array('parentCat' => $catID));

            if (is_numeric($subCatCountResult))
            {
                $PerPage = 9; //how many locations you want to show per page

                $subCatLastPage = ceil($subCatCountResult/$PerPage);

                if ($subCatLastPage < 1)
                {
                    $subCatLastPage = 1;
                }

                $pageNum = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? trim($_GET['pg']) : 1;    
                $pageNum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $pageNum);

                //////////////////////////////////////////////////

                $subCatLimit = 'LIMIT ' . ($pageNum - 1) * $PerPage . ',' . $PerPage;

                //////////////////////////////////////////////////

                $itemList = array(
                    'subCats' => array(),
                    'photos' => array()
                );

                if ($subCatListResult = $db->select("SELECT * FROM subCats WHERE parentCat = %s ORDER BY title $subCatLimit", $catID))
                {

                    if ($db->numRows > 0)
                    {
                        foreach ($subCatListResult as $row)
                        {

                            $photoID = 0;

                            if ($row['defaultPhoto'] == 0) //look up photo for
                            {

                                if ($firstPhotoResult = $db->select("SELECT id, time FROM photos WHERE subCat = '%s' ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1", $row['id']))
                                {
                                    if ($db->numRows > 0)
                                    {
                                        $photoID = $firstPhotoResult[0]['id'];
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $photoID = -1;
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $photoID = $row['defaultPhoto'];
                            }

                            //add to $itemList
                            $itemList['subCats'][$row['id']] = array(
                                'title' => $row['title']
                            );

                            $itemList['subCats'][$row['id']]['defaultPhoto'] = $photoID;

                        }

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    throwDBError();
                }

                function addPhotoToItemList($row)
                {
                    global $itemList;

                    $itemList['photos'][$row['id']] = array(
                        'title' => $row['title'],
                        'fileName' => $row['fileName'],
                        'fileType' => $row['fileType']
                    );

                    //

                }

                //get photos after subcats
                $photosOffset = 0;

                $grabPhotosCount = 9 - count($itemList['subCats']);

                if ($grabPhotosCount > 0)
                {

                    if ($result = $db->select("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE cat = %s and subCat = 0 ORDER BY title LIMIT 0, $grabPhotosCount", $catID))
                    {
                        if ($db->numRows > 0)
                        {
                            foreach ($result as $row)
                            {
                                $photosOffset++;
                                addPhotoToItemList($row);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throwDBError();
                    }


                }


                //get photos in maincat

                $photosCountResult = $db->count('photos', '*', array('cat' => $catID, 'subCat' => 0));

                if (is_numeric($photosCountResult))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    throwDBError();
                }

                if ($pageNum < 1)
                {
                    $pageNum = 1;
                }
                else if ($pageNum > $subCatLastPage) //get photos
                {
                    if (count($itemList) < 9)
                    {
                        //load in photos for cat




                    }

                    //redirect('/gallery/?cat=' . $catID . '&pg=' . $lastPage);
                }

                //pagination
                $totalCounts = $grabPhotosCount + $subCatCountResult;

                $lastPage = ceil($totalCounts/$PerPage);

                if ($lastPage < 1)
                {
                    $lastPage = 1;
                }

                $pageNum = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? trim($_GET['pg']) : 1;    
                $pageNum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $pageNum);





            }
            else
            {
                throwDBError();
            }

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($itemList);
            echo '</pre>';

        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div align="center">Category not found.</div>';
        }

    }
    else
    {
        throwDBError();
    }
?>
```

Comment: yes, you can. For real answers, show real code

Comment: Your description is confusing and unclear.  Give us the code you're using and we'll either clean it up or give you a thumbs up.

Comment: added my messy start. The idea is it will list out all the subcats for the cat and then list all the photos in the main cat.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a row number variable and then select from that derived table.  Taking a stab at what your table structure might be, something like this could work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT  p.id, 
          p.title, 
          sc.title as subcat_title,
          @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
  FROM    photos p 
  INNER JOIN subCats sc on p.subcat = sc.id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
  ) AS tbl
WHERE row_number>3 AND row_number<=6
```

Set the start and end paging row counts in the `WHERE` clause.

Here is a fiddle for the above: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/107f7/9/0